# None of the $Network merge fields working in Visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, network

None of the `$Network` merge fields are working when I test a `visualforce` email template, using a valid `User` and `Contact` combination.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Welcome to X" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Contact">
  <messaging:htmlemailbody>

  <p>Dear {!recipient.FirstName},</p>

  <p>$Network.ActionForVerificationEmail: {!$Network.ActionForVerificationEmail}</p>
  <p>$Network.AsyncVerificationLink: {!$Network.AsyncVerificationLink}</p>
  <p>$Network.BrowserForVerificationEmail: {!$Network.BrowserForVerificationEmail}</p>
  <p>$Network.CodeForVerificationEmail: {!$Network.CodeForVerificationEmail}</p>
  <p>$Network.Name: {!$Network.Name}</p>
  <p>$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails: {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}</p>
  <p>$Network.OperatingSystemForVerificationEmail: {!$Network.OperatingSystemForVerificationEmail}</p>

  </messaging:htmlemailbody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

And output is:

> Dear Tim Berners-Lee,
>   $Network.ActionForVerificationEmail:
>   $Network.AsyncVerificationLink:
>   $Network.BrowserForVerificationEmail:
>   $Network.CodeForVerificationEmail:
>   $Network.Name:
>   $Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails:
>   $Network.OperatingSystemForVerificationEmail:

No merged values!

The [Visualforce Developer Guide: $Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_network.htm), clearly states it should work in `visualforce`

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I get these merge fields to work?

Comment: Can you explain if you tried the Test functionality of the email template or tried with a real user? I remember a long time ago that Test functionality was not working for me but it was working if I used the whole flow to create a test user.

Comment: are you testing this when actually logged in as a Community User? doc states that it only works in that context

Answer (score 1):

The $network variables values will be available only in the community context.

Boolean res = System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation('005g0000007OzRX','00Xg0000000PYLVEA4','0DB12000000CaVnGAK', '/s/contactsupport'); this will sent the AsyncVerificationLink if it's called from the community context.

If you try to call this out of the community context, the value will be empty.

The same way other network variables work only in community context.
[image]

[image]

[Network variable informations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_network.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue where I was trying to send a community welcome email to a new users with the sendWelcomeEmail=false in the site. We needed this because some users have SSO and some do not.

Trying to the send the vf template using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage() wasn't working for me.

I found that if you call system.resetPasswordWithEmailTemplate() and specify the standard Community Welcome Email Template this works.

**My implementation:**

```
system.resetPasswordWithEmailTemplate(u.Id, true, 'CommunityWelcomeEmailTemplate');
```